# Dynamic routing with multiple parameters in Next js - File Structure

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

I want to create dynamic pages in nextjs to match the following route `users/[user]/[dashboard]`. My file structure

```
pages/
 users/
  -[user].js       // will match for /users/123
  - index.js        // will match for /users
    dashboard/
      - [dashboard].js   // will match for /users/1234/ABCD
```

I'm only receiving the `[user]` in the query param and not the [dashboard] inside the [dashboard].js . Can someone explain how to arrange file structure to match `users/[user]/[dashboard]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To match the following dynamic routes `users/[user]/[dashboard]` you can structure your `pages` folder as follows:

```
pages/
  users/      
    index.js        // Matches `/users` route
    [user]/   
      index.js      // Matches `/users/user123` routes
      [dashboard]/
        index.js    // Matches `/users/user123/dashboardABC` routes
```